# Is this possible? Adding a local device of my home network in client network without firewall configuration at client side (VPN?)

Tags: routing, network, vpn, firewall

Let me explain what I want to achieve, but keep in mind that my networking knowledge is limited.

I want to login at a clients network to do some remote troubleshooting. And I want to use (for example) a tool on my local laptop to search all my network devices at this client over a specific UDP port. So I need to have an IP adress in the clients network and it would appear as if my laptop was just a local device on the client network. If the client has a VPN server I could just connect to it and this would be enough I assume. But the client doesn't have a VPN.

So what can I do?
I don't control the firewall or network setup at the client. Assume I have physical access at the clients network. Can I plugin a (embedded?) device with some software running on it (VPN client/ server) to which I connect my laptop?

Or are there existing solutions for this problem?

Comment: Sorry, networks that you don't control are explicitly off topic here, see the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

> Can I plugin a (embedded?) device with some software running on it
> (VPN client/ server) to which I connect my laptop?

What you propose is installing a backdoor in a network you do not control. This is a terrible idea. It could cause you serious troubles.

You need to work out a solution with the IT of the client. Do nothing by yourself.

Note that [network you do not control are off-topic here](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).